# How to add blank records for grouping based on formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I have one table and group the records using formula, based on a string field which is formed as time (HH:mm:ss)
Formula is as followings:

```
select Minute (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat}))
case 0 to 14: ReplicateString ("0", 2-len(TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0))) & TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0) & ":00:00"
case 15 to 29: ReplicateString ("0", 2-len(TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0))) & TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0) & ":15:00"
case 30 to 44: ReplicateString ("0", 2-len(TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0))) & TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0) & ":30:00"
case 45 to 59: ReplicateString ("0", 2-len(TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0))) & TOTEXT(Hour (TimeValue ({MASTER.Saat})),0) & ":45:00"
```

Actually, grouping works fine but my problem is that if there is no data in the table for a period, I can not show that in the report.

As an example;

Let my data has 5 records as following:

- 11:01:03
- 11:16:07
- 11:28:16
- 12:18:47
- 12:22:34

My report gives the result as following:

- Period | Total Records
- 11:00:00 | 1
- 11:15:00 | 2
- 12:15:00 | 2

In this situation, I can not show the periods (which are missing in the table) as 0 for Total Records. I have to show as follows:

- Period | Total Records
- 11:00:00 | 1
- 11:15:00 | 2
- **11:30:00 | 0**
- **11:45:00 | 0**
- **12:00:00 | 0**
- 12:15:00 | 2

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't group something that's not there. One way to solve this is to use a table that provides all of your intervals you want to look at (called a date, time or number table).

For your case create a table that contains all your period values (24x4). join the records you want to count to this table. In Crystal Reports group by the period values - your result set will contain the periods without any joined records - you can detect this and output a `0`.

You may want to look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663355/counting-open-tickets-for-each-day-for-a-given-period-crystal-reports-11-0-0-8), it is similar to yours.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping that crystal reports would give a chance to solve such situations. Before applying an hard coded method like your suggestion, I wanted to make sure. Thanks for your reply.